# How is Machine Learning Overfitting works

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

How noise in the data, target complexity and size of the training set are related to over-fitting?

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I am guessing that you are a beginner, suppose you have dataset with lots of features(as in columns). you create a model and test it on your training and test dataset, you notice that it gives you an accuracy of 100 percent on your training set and 60-70 on your test set, this is an example of **Overfitting**. it is because you have chosen a lot of features which were not related to predicting the outcome.

you can remove it by dropping those irrelevant columns(which are called as noise), apply K-fold cross validation on your data.

this video might help you get a better understanding

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Anq4PgdASsc